# J1 Visa: Am I allowed to make money in a foreign country?

Tags: usa, taxes, j-visa, india, non-residents

I am an Indian citizen, currently in my third year of J-1 visa working full-time here in the US.

One of the European university labs that I collaborate with proposed to me that it would like to pay me for research consultations. I am not an employee of that university and will be paid based on an invoice. The payment will get deposited in my home country's bank account. Am I allowed to make such money under J-1 visa terms?

-RD

Answer (score 1):

The potential issue is that your J-1 status only gives you authorization to perform work in the US within your J-1 program. This issue depends on whether you are physically located in the US while performing the work, regardless of the employer's location, payment method and payment location.

One option which might work for you is "Occasional Lectures or Consultations", as defined in [22 CFR 62.20(g)](https://www.nafsa.org/_/file/_/amresource/22cfr62.htm). This is an authorization you can obtain through your J-1 university's Responsible Officer (RO or ARO), which can authorize a J-1 scholar to do a limited amount of lectures or consultations for a different university or institution.